# Variation of behavior of regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I tried the following code in python

```
>>> pattern="(.*?)\s+in\s+[^\(](.*?)"
>>> a=" i am in (india)"
>>> re.search(pattern,a).group()
```

Got this, which is the expected output

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

>>> b="i am in india"
>>> re.search(pattern,b).group()
'i am in i'
```

which is also expected output

```
>>> c=' i am in               (india)'
>>> re.search(pattern,c).group()
' i am in               '
```

Here I was expecting `NoneType`, but instead got the above output. Why does the case vary between `a` and `c`?

Comment: You can only select one accepted answer at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[^\(]` matches spaces as well, as does `.`.

In case *A* the `\s+` matches the *one* space, but cannot match the `(`. But in case *B* `\s+` matches all spaces before `(` except the last one, where `[^\(]` matches the last space, satisfying the pattern.

Comment: Thank you Totem and Martijn.
What will be the regex if i wanted to check the following condition
anything space in space anything_except_open_bracket anything

Answer (score 1):

`[^\(]` matches anything except `(`, including white space(spaces).

`.`(the dot) matches anything at all except `\n`(newline character) also including spaces

Comment: what will be the regex to get a match in following cases
i am in  russia
and no match in this case
i am in  (russia

Comment: Just a heads up - [^\(] matches anything except `(` .[^\\\(] matches anything except backslash and `(`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! Edited